# Fragment views are null even after initialization

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, butterknife

I have a unique problem:

I have a viewpager tied to a tabLayout in an Activity. There are 5 tabs to the tablayout so 5 different fragments to them. There is a spinner in the Activity whose value defines what each of the fragment will show when the user accesses the tab. So i have created a callback mechanism by which when the user either slides or taps on the tab, the callback is called to all the fragments from the activity notifying if the fragment is being shown to the user or not. Based on that the view is further drawn with the values.

This works like a charm for me. The problem arises when the application is left in background (not killed/finished) for some 30 mins or 1 hour or more. I have ASUS Zen mobile which has boost memory feature which if I use then I am able to recreate the problem easily.

The problem is, after a long time (appears Android cleans up the views for memory), when I again launch the application, it tries to draw the same view again (without starting with the splash screen) and that is correct. the onAttach(Activity) of the fragments are called after the onCreate of the Activity is completed. I am using butterknife 7.0.1 to bind the view. The fragment's onCreateView is also called, and I can see that the recyclerview object also gets binded and is initialized with a value. When I tap on the tab, the callback is called to this fragment and at that time I see that the same recyclerview is null. This happens only when we try to launch the application after a while and otherwise it works so well.

I have spent 2 days on this but i am clueless who makes the object null or what is happening.

[SOLVED]

Editing now after finding the solution.

Problem: The OS used to remember the the instance before it was cleared by onSavedInstance that is received in the Activity's onCreate, and we call upon super.onCreate(onSavedInstance);

This basically was the reason why we used to have the fragment in initialized state, and then the view pager as a part of the activity was trying to create new Fragment. I am not sure why the onCreateView of the fragment was not called when new fragment was created. But nonetheless, by passing null to super.onCreate(null) for the activity's onCreate basically ensured that no state is saved and we get a clean new launch which works.

Comment: Some code that we can use to reproduce the problem would be nice.

Comment: I further debugged with different perspective. found the problem. the os indeed clears the fragments and the activities and when we start the app again,it tries to recreate from its saved instances. however what happens is that the viewpager is newly created, and hence the new fragments are created. but before viewpager creates new fragments, the old savedinstances are tried out by the OS and hence we see that the recyclerview has an instance and later on it does not have any instance.The problem now is when new instance of frag is created by viewpager then onCreateView of new frag isnt called

Comment: Is there a better way? Because I want to save the state of other viewpager pages, only refresh the fragment of TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced the same issue and it can be reproduced easily:
Go to Developer options -> Apps -> Don't keep activities and enable it.
By this, the OS cleaning can be simulated and waiting for hours for to reproduce the crash can be avoided.